# How do you serve static files when using the django runserver development server?

Tags: django

I am using django 1.5

I am able to serve the files in production because it is being handled at the apache level. Here is my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/membership/membership/wsgi.py

Alias /static/ "/home/membership/static/"


<Directory /home/membership/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/membership/membership>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine in production because of the `Alias /static/ "/home/membership/static/"`

When I try and run the app in my local development environment I can't get it to serve static files I just get a page not found 404 error. I am guess that this is because when I develop locally the requests are going straight to the development server since apache is not being used.

[image]

I do have a file at /static/me.png .

Is there somewhere that I am supposed to specify to serve static files in development?

When running `python manage.py collectstatic` it seems to collect only the static files for the admin app. I have a file directly in the /app/static directory that I am trying to serve.

Comment: did you ran in the server `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you define the path to your static files in your site's settings? I don't mean the url `/static/`, I mean the `STATICFILES_DIR` (it's what tells your devserver where the static files are just like the config file tells the `apache`)

It's really best to just follow the documentation, it is absolutley fantastic:

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: No I have not set that. I will give it a try. I have a feeling that is what the problem is.

Answer (score 19):

**If you're Serving static files during development**

On your **settings.py** file:

```
# Add it on your settings.py file
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), # your static/ files folder
]
```

Example:

[image]

On your root **urls.py** file:

```
# add these lines
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# Add +static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Example:

[image]

This is not suitable for production use! See more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

For media files on **media/** directory:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: This is not just an answer, it's a blog post! :). Thanks! I was missing the urlpatterns part.

Answer (score 4):

In your `urls.py`, simply add this at the bottom:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^stati_directory/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),)
```

Make sure `DEBUG = True`

Answer (score 0):

In the `settings.py` file update the following lines.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,’’)]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
```

1. Create a folder called media inside static and keep all your media files inside that.
2. Run **python manage.py collectstatic** to collect all your third party application static files including django admin static files.
3. In the main `url.py` add the following lines to serve as a url.

   ```
   from django.conf.urls.static import static
   from django.conf import settings

   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```