# How to link HTML and CSS file using Django?

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am novice person to Django learning.
I have tried with simple linking HTML and CSS files in Django by referring some sites and videos but it seems CSS file is not included. Though I tried multiple times I am not getting the background color which I put in CSS file.
CSS file saved in static/css/style.css

```
body{
    background-color: violet;
}
```

HTML file saved in templates/bg.html

```
{%load static%}
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title> BG </title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>        
        <h2 class="bg_class">BG Colour</h2>
        <p>
        Background Color is to be changed.<br>
        </p>
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I have configured the static file in settings.py file too.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

Instead of ‘violet’ background, I am still getting ‘white’ background.
Kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: Share your work tree. To Receive accurate result.

Comment: Sometimes cache memory prevents CSS files to work. Try to clear cache from your browser from settings. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving your static files?

If you are running the `manage.py runserver` you might want to add this to the end of your projects `urls.py`:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

like here: https://github.com/almazkun/durls/blob/4b17a1b698430b442fc1e74e5b24f792f57cb17e/settings/urls.py#L28
or here:
[How do you serve static files when using the django runserver development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713703/how-do-you-serve-static-files-when-using-the-django-runserver-development-server)

Note that `Django` does not serve `static` and `media` files itself. You will need to setup it separetatly using things like `nginx` or `whitenoise`.

Answer (score 0):

To managing the static file. First you need to know the `development` and `production` setup.

- In development you need to set `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`
- In production you need to set  `DEBUG=False` in `settings.py`

### Development

For serving the static file in development project. You need to do two things .

First one is changing the `settings.py` file. Added this sample code.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
        '/static/',
    ]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Second change is `urls.py` file. Add added this sample code-

```
## import this at the top
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns



## bottom of the file `urls.py` 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

You can check out this django project. how you can change your code **[Repo Link](https://github.com/Rafat97/my-so-solutions/tree/71261202/Django/test_71261202)**.

### Production

For production build you must follow this **[checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/)**.
After completing checklist, you can serve your static content using `nginx` web-server. Or you can use `whitenoise` python package.

- [Configure static files to work with NGINX](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/configure-static-files-to-work-with-nginx/5689) or [Medium blog(Configuring Django Static files with Nginx)](https://medium.com/clercode/configuring-django-static-files-with-nginx-1943257c17ad)
- [Using WhiteNoise with Django](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html).

I think it will help your further working.